# ElasticsearchSecurityException[action [indices:admin/get/relation] is unauthorized for user [elastic]

Tags: elasticsearch

I customized a Action that works normally with config property *xpack.security.enabled: false*. After reading the documentation about x-pack security, I tried to configure permissions, but failed. Can anyone help me, thanks.

my code

```
public class RelationAdminGetAction extends Action<RelationAdminGetRequest, RelationAdminGetResponse, RelationAdminGetRequestBuilder> {

    public final static String NAME = "indices:admin/get/relation";

    public final static RelationAdminGetAction INSTANCE = new RelationAdminGetAction();

    private RelationAdminGetAction() {
        super(NAME);
    }
    ...

}
```

error

```
ElasticsearchSecurityException[action [indices:admin/get/relation] is unauthorized for user [elastic]
]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.support.Exceptions.authorizationError(Exceptions.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.denialException(AuthorizationService.java:511)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.denial(AuthorizationService.java:482)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorize(AuthorizationService.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.lambda$authorizeAsync$5(ServerTransportFilter.java:190)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationUtils$AsyncAuthorizer.maybeRun(AuthorizationUtils.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationUtils$AsyncAuthorizer.setRunAsRoles(AuthorizationUtils.java:121)
```

Comment: what permissions does that user's role have?

Comment: After I configured *xpack.security.enabled: true*, the above error appeared

Comment: elastic is the superuser, It should have all permissons